# how to extract a specific part from pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf, extract, text-extraction

I want to ask about extracting/getting a specific part of words from a PDF using PHP.

For example, I want to get the whole text of abstract part from a journal to input it to my database.

Does anyone know a tool or how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.pdfparser.org/

Comment: If the GPL restriction of the given link by @smarber is a problem and if you need to extract text from specific areas you may take a look at our [text extractor](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/demos/extract-words-by-a-specific-location/) component (not free!).

Comment: thanks, 
but using text extractor is like using a snipping tools
and I don't really need it. 
I want my system automatically get the content from pdf automatically by only giving a start and end parameter in the code. 
the content that I want to get is always at the first page, 
but in the first page, it's contain not only the part that I want to take, but also contain another text that I don't need